# HAML link_to in rails does not apply a class on page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

The problem with the below script is that the below code makes releases.content active only after the page refresh not during the first page load . I am new to writing a haml template . Anything evidently wrong that I might be doing here ?

```
%li.accordion-navigation
      = link_to "Last 10 Releases", "#releases" 
      #releases.content.active
        %table.grid
          %thead
            %tr
              %th Build
              %th Deployed at
              %th Report
          %tbody
            - @last_deployments.each do |deployment|
              %tr
                %td= deployment.build
                %td= deployment.deployed_date
                %td
                  = link_to "detail", certification_path(deployment.certification)
    %li.accordion-navigation
      = link_to "Current Bug Status", "#bug_status"
      #bug_status.content.active \w
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code instead even its same -

```
%div.content.active{ id: 'releases' }
```